# CentOS 7 Symfony 2 Unable to create the cache directory Issue

Tags: linux, apache, symfony, centos

Reaching out in the vain hope of someone being able to point out a correct set of commands required to set my CLI user and web server user as the same.

**I have tried searching extensively on this site as well as others and attempted the suggestions but to no avail**

As far as I understand the issue I have boils down to the above, and hopefully getting both users to match will allow symfony to be able to attain the correct permissions and be able to write the dev folder in app > cache.

Currently the cache folder is set to apache:apache.

When running `$ps aux | grep apache` I get a lot of "apache" in red and 1 root in grey (I understand the colours may not translate to other users) so from this; which i confess to not being overly confident with suggests the CLI is already set to apache:apache?

Oh BTW the server I am using is a local dev server in a LAMP stack env running CentOS 7

Any other info you need just ask and I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Can you show `ls -la /absolute_path/app/cache` ?
What are the permissions in path to app folder?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 2 apache:apache

Comment: I mean a path to your app folder. it is / or /tmp… where is it and what are permissions before

Comment: /var/www/dev-master/<foldername> all folders in that path are set to 755